# How can I view python library functions in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+left-click in the name of function to view library functions in PyCharm, and I want to do the same in VScode; what should I do?

I may not be very clear, so I recorded a gif.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@cnkl, what you're after is the 'go to definition' feature. 
You can go to the definition of a symbol by pressing F12.
If you press Ctrl and hover over a symbol, a preview of the declaration will appear

You can find more details here: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition

Comment: I know that,but if the function was defined in the standard library,such as math.fabs(),then pressing F12 have no effect.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I stumple upon this question, and with the latest vscode (version 1.17.2), I found when I move my mouse and hover on the standard library, I can see the python doc like this:
[hover over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVnBq.png)